# Defining a function that maps to a vector of variable size

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I am trying to define a function that takes a vector and a set of indicies and returns a vector that only contains the elements associated with some subset of the set of indicies.

Given some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, a set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, and a set of indices $I=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, with some subset of indices $\mathcal{I}\in \mathscr{P}(I)$. We could (incorrectly) define a function that returns a vector containing the elements of $a \in A$ corresponding to the indicies in $\mathcal{I}$ like so:

$f: A \times \mathscr{P}(I) \to \mathbb{R}^{|\mathcal{I}|}, (a,\mathcal{I}) \mapsto (a_{\mathcal{I}_1},a_{\mathcal{I}_2},\dots,a_{\mathcal{I}_{|\mathcal{I}|}})$

For example, $a = (2,4,6,8)$, $\mathcal{I} = \{1,3,4\}$ would give $f(a,\mathcal{I}) = (2,6,8)$.

My problem is that I am certain that the part $\to \mathbb{R}^{|\mathcal{I}|}$ is wrong, because $\mathcal{I}$ is an element of $\mathscr{P}(I)$, and doesn't get mentioned until the second part of the function declaration.

I am also certain that it shouldn't be $\to \mathbb{R}^{|\mathscr{P}(I)|}$, as that is the size of the power set of $I$. So how do I denote the size of the vector that is being mapped to, in the first part of the function declaration?

Comment: Strictly speaking you would have to denote the range of $f$ as $\bigsqcup_{i=0}^n\mathbb{R}^i$, that is the disjoint union of all target spaces of dimension $i$.

Comment: ah cool, i didnt know about the disjoint union, I will do some reading now.. thanks. If you want to make it an answer i will accept it